# AngularJS | angular-permissions role validation

Tags: angularjs, permissions

Hello Oh Holy stackoverflow!

I am trying to use angular-permissions to create three roles for my app. User, Admin and Partner. I read the entire wiki and this is what I have come up with:

```
.run(function (PermPermissionStore, PermRoleStore) {

var userPermissionsArray = ['seeUserDashboard'];
var adminPermissionsArray = ['seeAdminDashboard'];
var partnerPermissionsArray = ['seePartnerDashboard'];

PermRoleStore
.defineManyRoles({
    'USER' : userPermissionsArray,
    'ADMIN' : adminPermissionsArray,
    'PARTNER' : partnerPermissionsArray
});

PermPermissionStore
.defineManyPermissions(userPermissionsArray, function (permissionName) {
    return _.contains(userPermissionsArray, permissionName);
});
PermPermissionStore
.defineManyPermissions(adminPermissionsArray, function (permissionName) {
    return _.contains(userPermissionsArray, permissionName);
});
PermPermissionStore
.defineManyPermissions(partnerPermissionsArray, function (permissionName) {
    return _.contains(userPermissionsArray, permissionName);
});

})
```

My question is this. How do I validate and assign the current session a particular role? Also, am I assigning the permissions to the role correctly? My thought is to have a validation API call that runs and the API will spit back the role that the clients token resolved to. I want to do something like this but defineManyRoles doesn't return a promise!

```
PermRoleStore
.defineManyRoles({
    'USER' : userPermissionsArray,
    'ADMIN' : adminPermissionsArray,
    'PARTNER' : partnerPermissionsArray
})
.then(function onSuccess() {
    return $http.put('/api/validation/global')
    .then(function onSuccess(res) {
        return $q.resolve();
    })
    .catch(function onError(res) {
        return $q.reject();
    });
})
.catch(function onError(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that before I removed angular permission from our project with

```
PermPermissionStore.defineManyPermissions($rootScope.authService.getPermissionGroups(), function (stateParams, permissionName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(angular.isDefined($rootScope.authService.userId)) {
        $rootScope.authService.userPromise
            .then(function (data) {
                if($rootScope.authService.hasPermission(permissionName)) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            }).catch(function () {
                deferred.reject();
            });
    } else {
        deferred.reject();
    }

    return deferred.promise;
});
```